# Click event isn't fired when using custom button control

Tags: c#, events, click, custom-controls

I have made custom button control, but I'm missing something because I can't get it work properly.

Button works if render method is like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
  base.Render(writer);
}
```

But when I change code to this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, css);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.UniqueID);
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, this.ID);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
        writer.Write(base.Text);
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
        writer.RenderEndTag();
    }
```

It just loads same page where button was clicked and nothing else happens.

So what I'm not doing what base.Render(write) does? And is there anything else in these custom control buttons what should be done or can I do this better?

Buttons output should be something like:

```
<button>
  <span>
    <span>
      <span>
        Title
      </span>
    </span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should invoke the base method...

```
base.Render(writer);
```

Like below ↓

```
  protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Class, css);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Id, this.UniqueID);
            writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.Name, this.ID);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Button);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Span);
            writer.Write(base.Text);
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();
            writer.RenderEndTag();

　　　　　　　base.Render(writer);
        }
```

Comment: Now it does two buttons next to each other. Second one is working fine (I think base.render(writer) does that), but the first one isn't, and that's the one which has correct layout made with css. I just realized that maybe I need to do this with LinkButton, because it allows automatically to add child controls.